# jQuery - inserting clicked text value of multiple buttons

Tags: jquery

This is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sungsoonz/L2Ssq/15/) I've been working on for a proof of concept.

What I am trying to achieve is when buttons are clicked from the bottom container
I want to indicate the clicked button's text value below top menu navigation like a breadcrumb path to make user aware which buttons are clicked.

For the moment I cannot find jQuery functions that can branch and filter those clicked by id or class so I can append those clicked text value into the correct position below top menu navigation.

Another challenging part for me is to stack all button values that are clicked
rather than only displaying one button value at a time in case users click multiple buttons.
This is to give a user friendly indication of the full path of a page they are on a production site.
According to jQuery documentation there are functions like `append()` `push()` but I guess their usage aren't exactly what I am trying to accomplish.

**- Edited my question and added illustration**

[image]

Comment: You'll need some sort of hierarchy to keep of track of main pages, sub pages, sub-sub pages etc.

Comment: I don't understand your question. You already get the text from clicked button.

Comment: The question is unclear. Could you maybe explain with an example?

Comment: Thanks for showing your support and I apologise for any confusion. I've edited my question with some picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is attach some sort of identifying attribute to the buttons that will allow you to determine what the target is. The methodology I choose was to add custom data attributes with the appropriate target IDs as the value. Then, inside the click event handler, I passed the custom data attribute value as the new jquery selector to select the right DOM element we want to append the text to.

[Working example here.](http://jsfiddle.net/L2Ssq/20/)

The important code:

```
//An example button with the custom data attribute with a target as its value
<button class="btn" data-target="forDate">Today</button>

//The modified click event 
$("button").click(function () {
    var text = $(this).text();
    var target = '#' + $(this).data().target;
    $(target).html(text);
});
```

### EDIT

If you want to stack the button values as they are clicked, you can do so [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/L2Ssq/26/).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I chose your answer for the neatness and I learned the new concept like data-target. Out of interest though, if I want to stack all values that are clicked from one set, for example, clicking "today", then "tomorrow", won't replace today but display "tomorrow" on a new line, how can I do this?

Comment: @SeongLee You can store the previous html inside a variable, then when you specify the target using the custom data attribute you first add the old html then the new clicked value. I added an updated fiddle to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not really sure what you're after but I think it's something like this:

```
$("div.jc > button.btn").click(function () {
    var text = $(this).text();
    $("#jc").html(text);
});

$("div.date > button.btn").click(function () {
    var text = $(this).text();
    $("#date").html(text);
});

$("div.jp > button.btn").click(function () {
    var text = $(this).text();
    $("#jp").html(text);
});

$("div.ws > button.btn").click(function () {
    var text = $(this).text();
    $("#ws").html(text);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/L2Ssq/18/

Comment: Thank you and apologise if my question was not descriptive enough.
You got the hang of my problem but I want to insert those text values under the top menu like the illustration I added.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/L2Ssq/25/

You need to add some classes to the button sections, and do a bit of formatting

```
$("button").click(function () {
    btn = $(this);
    btn.parent().children().removeClass('clicked');
    btn.addClass('clicked');

    $("#forDate").text( $('.btns-date > .btn.clicked').text() );
    $("#forJC").text( $('.btns-job-cat > .btn.clicked').text() );
    $("#forJP").text( $('.btns-job-pri > .btn.clicked').text() );
    $("#forWS").text( $('.btns-wf-status > .btn.clicked').text() );
});
```